# Write a recursive function that takes an array and displays the elements in reverse order without starting the index of the array at the end

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion

My question is: Am I doing this right or not?
Because no one can tell me exactly...

Write a recursive function that takes an array and displays the elements in reverse order
without starting the index of the array at the end. (In other words, don’t write the equivalent of
a loop that starts printing at the end of the array.)

```
int bleah(int arr[], int number)
{
    cout << arr[number] << ' ';
    if (number <= 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    cout << arr[number] << ' ';
    return bleah(arr, number - 1);
}

int main()
{
    int arr[31] = {0};
    for (int i = 0; i <= 30; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = i;
    }
    bleah(arr, 30);

    cin.get();
    cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: _"Because no one can tell me exactly..."_ What do your test cases say?

Comment: It's ok. There are no errors or like stack overflow problems.
The output is through 30 to 0.
Am I doing this right according to the task?

Comment: Ask your professor, how should I know?

Comment: There is no professor. I'm doing this for myself.
If you can't help, so why are you answering my question? What's the point?

Comment: Sorry with the given information I simply can't answer your question. You can apply test cases (including edge cases) to be able to answer that for yoourself. Does your function work well for all your test cases? _Did you miss any requirements for the task?_ is another question.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate.  That nonexistent professor should make instructions clearer...  See:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25656821/understanding-a-recursive-solution-to-print-out-an-array-in-reversed-order

Comment: That's funny. Because the name of nonexistent professor is Alex Allain. And this task is from his book called "Jumping into C++".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry people for wasting your time!
I finally got the answer and looked for it on Github.
This is the right answer

```
void bleah(int arr[], int number)
{
    if (number + 1 < 10)
    {
        bleah(arr, number + 1);
    }
    cout << arr[number] << ' ';
}

int main()
{
    int arr[11] = { 34,5,8,3,6,678,8,87,67,8 };
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;
    bleah(arr, 0);

    cin.get();
    cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are doing it exactlly like you didn't want to. you said you was asked to write a recursive function that not starting at the end, but you send the last cell.

try use the recursive like this:

```
void bleah(int arr[], int number)
{
    if (number != arr.length()-1)
        bleah(arr, number + 1);
    cout << arr[number] << ' ';
}
```

and call it:

```
bleah(arr, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying mate!
I'm the beginner, don't judge me too strictly.

Comment: @Nick Though you should learn how to ask good questions here. Your question is simply uncear (_@LionP_ made it obvious you were simply missing the tasks requirement). You didn't state anything what goes wrong with your code example.

Comment: Got it. Next time I'll consider this.

Comment: @Nick Probably better you consider this in time just now, and improve your question. Anything else will lead you to being blocked here asking any question any more.

Answer (score 0):

A complete running code (along with main method). I understand it's bit difficult for a beginner in the starting. Don't bother about harsh comments here.
I have used a vector rather than traditional array just to make things simpler and readable:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
//Typedef the vector to a simple name, array
typedef vector<int> array;

//The actual, recursive function
void printReverse(const array arr, const unsigned int index){
    //The base condition of recursion
    if(index != arr.size()){
        printReverse(arr, index+1);
        cout << arr[index] <<" ";
    }
}

int main()
{
    int size;
    cout << "Enter size of the array: ";
    cin >> size;
    array arr;

    cout << "Enter elements: ";
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        int a;
        cin >> a;
        arr.push_back(a); //add the input to the array(or vector)
    }
    //The recursive function call(starting with index 0)
    printReverse(arr, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That will do! But I need to solve this with an array.

Comment: @Nick Then simply replace vector with array. Vector is internally an array only. If you look at printReverse() method, there is no difference in the syntax. Just receive array reference as parameter instead of vector. :)